# Custom checkBox with midle alligned label text

Tags: html, css, dom

i have a custom checkbox markup with label warped please check this link

jsfiddle.net/jhCH2/4/

I need to middle align the lable text with respect to the check-box div.

please note that the learn more link should be outside label element and same line of label.

Comment: **IT IS** middle aligned. And why the huge line of inline styles?

Comment: your code was one mess...please format before posting!!

Answer (score 1):

**you cannot vertically-align-middle a paragraph next to a check-box.....**

`Label` tag is for labels, not paragraphs, you should use `<p>` instead....
For middle alignment of `label` *not a paragrap* use :

```
label{
   vertical-align: middle
}
```

[**demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/jhCH2/3/)

EDIT

[**indented demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jhCH2/9/)

- You'll have to use `float:left` to indent the text.
- Also, since you have `absolute` positioned divs, move the `input` out of `label` to indent it, like :

`<input type="checkbox" name="cb" />
<label for="cb"></label>`

Comment: Thnx Noob, but i am trying out to get same text indent for label when there is multipleline label text. jsfiddle.net/jhCH2/6/ (all text need to be with same margin)